# javascript loop through dates - stop and display correct date

Tags: javascript, loops, date, web-applications, local-storage

I have a loop that checks the current date against the week from sunday-saturday and then check if it is past, current or due. It ALWAYS SHOWS next week!

logic is as follows

If it is the current weekday then display todays date, 
if it is a past weekday then display that date + 7 to get next weeks date,
if it is a day coming up then display that date.

Here is the code that I have put together.

```
document.getElementById('youchose').innerHTML = localStorage.day;

window.myDate = new Date(); 
if(localStorage.getItem("setDate") != null && localStorage.setDate != null && localStorage.setDate!="0000-00-00" && localStorage.setDate!=""){
    a = localStorage.setDate;
    a = a.split("-");
    if(a.length >= 1){
        window.myDate= new Date(a[0],a[1]-1,a[2]);
    } else {
        window.myDate = new Date(); 
    }
}
var weekdays = new Array();
weekdays['Sunday'] = 0;
weekdays['Monday'] = 1;
weekdays['Tuesday'] = 2;
weekdays['Wednesday'] = 3;
weekdays['Thursday'] = 4;
weekdays['Friday'] = 5;
weekdays['Saturday'] = 6;

//loop starts

for(weeki=0; weeki <= 7; weeki++){
    if(window.myDate.getDay() == weekdays[localStorage.day]){ //for current day
        SelectFromDB();
        window.myDate.setDate(window.myDate.getDate());
        weeki = 100;
        break;
    }else if(window.myDate.getDay() > weekdays[localStorage.day]) { //for previous days
        window.myDate.setDate(window.myDate.getDate()-1);
    }else{
        window.myDate.setDate(window.myDate.getDate()+1); // for next days
    }
}
```

It won't it just keeps adding 7 to all the dates. 
what am I missing. been staring at this for days it seems.

Thanks for any help

Comment: Since this isn't a direct answer to your question I'll put it here. If you're working with dates a lot in javascript, then I would look at http://momentjs.com/

Comment: Thanks Luke, I will look into that. I imagine using the moment.min and moment.max would make it simpler?

Comment: To be honest, I'm a little confused as to what you're trying to accomplish. If you're trying to get something like a due date on a deadline (to see if it's past due, due, or how long until it's due) you could use `moment(dateobject).isBefore(dateobject)` and/or `moment(dateobject).isAfter(dateobject)` and then `.from(date)` and `.to(date)`

Comment: Here's a codepen you can play with that has jquery and momentjs  
http://codepen.io/luke3butler/pen/wGbXZO

Comment: this is for finding your garbage pick up day. So say it is tuesday. if your pickup is on monday then would like to show next monday. If today show next tuesday (since you missed you the pickup) and then for w/t/f show the upcoming dates for each. Does that make more sense? I feel the code there is bloated to something simple.

Comment: Is this an assignment? I can remember answering a very similar question a few months ago.

Comment: @Luke3butler—the OP's issue has nothing to do with manipulating dates and seems to be correctly parsing the value retrieved from local storage.

Comment: This wasn't an assignment but I did hire a guy to fix it and he did not. If it was then I would love to find out so I can get my money back.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not a complete answer as there are issues with just about every line of your code.

The use of *window* properties instead of variable declarations works, but it is probably better to use variable declarations rather than property assignments, so instead of:

```
window.myDate = new Date();
```

consider:

```
var myDate = new Date();
```

which has subtle but useful benefits. Similarly, accessing global variables as *window.varName* is just a long winded way of accessing *varName* and is problematic if the code is intended to be run in a non–browser host (which this doesn't appear to be, but not a good habit).

Then:

```
if(localStorage.getItem("setDate") != null && localStorage.setDate != null && localStorage.setDate!="0000-00-00" && localStorage.setDate!=""){
```

The [*localStorage* API](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/webstorage.html#the-storage-interface) is very simple, it only has a couple of methods, there is no "setDate" method so the above will always return false since *localStorage.setDate* will return *undefined* which == null.

So none of the code in the *if* block will run.

Also there is:

```
var weekdays = new Array();
weekdays['Sunday'] = 0;
```

Arrays are just objects with a special length property. The above creates an array, then treats it as a plain object and is equivalent to:

```
var weekdays = new Object();
weekdays['Sunday'] = 0;
```

Most would code it using an object literal:

```
var weekdays = {Sunday: 0, Monday: 1, Tuesday: 2, Wednesday: 3,
                Thursday: 4, Friday: 5, Saturday: 6};
```

Presumably the value returned from local storage is something like '2016-05-19', which you then correctly parse to a Date.

Then:

```
if (window.myDate.getDay() > weekdays[localStorage.day])
```

Doesn't seem correct, perhaps you meant:

if (window.myDate.getDay() > weekdays[localStorage.getItem('day')])

Anyway, that is a start on your issues.

Comment: Thanks so much Rob, I inherited this code and am trying to make some sense of it. You have really helped out. Thanks again.

Comment: There were issues with every line. I am glad you mentioned that because I was able to deflate the situation with the client by sending them your comment. Cheers!